# ReferenceError: function is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Tags: javascript

There is a possibility to select an excel file. Then click on upload and the code will get started. When I press the 'upload' button I get the

> '(index): 57 Uncaught ReferenceError: Upload is not defined
>        at HTMLInputElement.onclick '

I tried to place the `<script>` in the head, within the `<body>` in the beginning and at the end of the page, now I have separated the js file from the html file and it is loaded in the head.

```js
var aerobic = ['Totalbalance', 'Powerpump', 'HIT training', 'Cardio Fitness', 'Yoga'];
var crossbox = ['WOD- les', 'Circuit training'];

function Upload() {
    //Reference the FileUpload element.
    var fileUpload = document.getElementById("fileUpload");

    //Validate whether File is valid Excel file.
    var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.xls|.xlsx)$/;
    if (regex.test(fileUpload.value.toLowerCase())) {
        if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            //For Browsers other than IE.
            if (reader.readAsBinaryString) {
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    ProcessExcel(e.target.result);
                };
                reader.readAsBinaryString(fileUpload.files[0]);
            } else {
                //For IE Browser.
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    var data = "";
                    var bytes = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
                    for (var i = 0; i < bytes.byteLength; i++) {
                        data += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
                    }
                    ProcessExcel(data);
                };
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileUpload.files[0]);
            }
        } else {
            alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
        }
    } else {
        alert("Please upload a valid Excel file.");
    }
}

function ProcessExcel(data) {
    //Read the Excel File data.
    var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
        type: 'binary'
    });

    //Fetch the name of First Sheet.
    var firstSheet = workbook.SheetNames[0];

    //Read all rows from First Sheet into an JSON array.
    var excelRows = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[firstSheet]);

    //Create a HTML Table element.
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    table.border = "1";

    //Add the header row.
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);

    //Add the header cells.
    var headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
    headerCell.innerHTML = "Datum";
    row.appendChild(headerCell);

    headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
    headerCell.innerHTML = "Starttijd";
    row.appendChild(headerCell);

    headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
    headerCell.innerHTML = "Eindtijd";
    row.appendChild(headerCell);

    headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
    headerCell.innerHTML = "Activiteit";
    row.appendChild(headerCell);

    //Add the data rows from Excel file.
    for (var i = 0; i < excelRows.length; i++) {
        //Add the data row.
        var row = table.insertRow(-1);

        //Add the data cells.
        var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
        cell.innerHTML = excelRows[i].Datum;

        cell = row.insertCell(-1);
        cell.innerHTML = excelRows[i].Starttijd;

        cell = row.insertCell(-1);
        cell.innerHTML = excelRows[i].Eindtijd;

        cell = row.insertCell(-1);
        cell.innerHTML = excelRows[i].Activiteit;
    }



    sortDates(excelRows);
}



function sortDates(excelRows) {
    // var spinning = [];
    var rest = [];
    var thisWeek = [];


    var curr = new Date; // get current date
    var first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay(); // First day is the day of the month - the day of the week
    var last = first + 7; // last day is the first day + 6

    var firstday = new Date(curr.setDate(first));
    var lastday = new Date(curr.setDate(last));

    for (var i = 0; i < excelRows.length; i++) {
        var parts = excelRows[i].Datum.split('-');
        var mydate = new Date(Date.UTC(parts[2], parts[1] - 1, parts[0]));
        if (new Date(mydate) > new Date(firstday) && new Date(mydate) < new Date(lastday)) {
            thisWeek.push(excelRows[i]);
        } else {
            rest.push(excelRows[i]);
        }
    }

    splitWeek(thisWeek);
}

function splitWeek(thisWeek) {


    var mondayData = [];
    var tuesdayData = [];
    var wednesdayData = [];
    var thursdayData = [];
    var fridayData = [];
    var saturdayData = [];
    var sundayData = [];

    var curr = new Date; // get current date
    var mon = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay(); // First day is the day of the month - the day of the week
    var monday = new Date(curr.setDate(mon));

    var tue = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay() + 1; // First day is the day of the month - the day of the week
    var tuesday = new Date(curr.setDate(tue));

    var wed = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay() + 2; // First day is the day of the month - the day of the week
    var wednesday = new Date(curr.setDate(wed));

    var thu = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay() + 3; // First day is the day of the month - the day of the week
    var thursday = new Date(curr.setDate(thu));

    var fri = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay() + 4; // First day is the day of the month - the day of the week
    var friday = new Date(curr.setDate(fri));

    var sat = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay() + 5; // First day is the day of the month - the day of the week
    var saturday = new Date(curr.setDate(sat));

    var sun = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay() + 6; // First day is the day of the month - the day of the week
    var sunday = new Date(curr.setDate(sun));

    for (var i = 0; i < thisWeek.length; i++) {
        var parts = thisWeek[i].Datum.split('-');
        var mydate = new Date(Date.UTC(parts[2], parts[1] - 1, parts[0]));

        if (mydate > monday && mydate < tuesday) {
            mondayData.push(thisWeek[i]);
        }
        if (mydate > tuesday && mydate < wednesday) {
            tuesdayData.push(thisWeek[i]);
        }
        if (mydate > wednesday && mydate < thursday) {
            wednesdayData.push(thisWeek[i]);
        }
        if (mydate > thursday && mydate < friday) {
            thursdayData.push(thisWeek[i]);
        }
        if (mydate > friday && mydate < saturday) {
            fridayData.push(thisWeek[i]);
        }
        if (mydate > saturday && mydate < sunday) {
            saturdayData.push(thisWeek[i]);
        }
        if (mydate > sunday) {
            sundayData.push(thisWeek[i]);
        }

    }

    // writeData(sortMonday(mondayData));


    viewMonday(sortMonday(mondayData));
    viewTuesday(sortTuesday(tuesdayData));
    viewWednesday(sortTuesday(wednesdayData));
    viewThursday(sortThursday(thursdayData));
    viewFriday(sortFriday(fridayData));
    viewSaturday(sortSaturday(saturdayData));
    viewSunday(sortSunday(sundayData));
}


function sortMonday(monday) {


    var aerobicMonday = [];

    var crossboxMonday = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < monday.length; i++) {
        if (aerobic.includes(monday[i].Activiteit)) {
            aerobicMonday.push(monday[i]);
        }
        if (crossbox.includes(monday[i].Activiteit)) {
            crossboxMonday.push(monday[i]);
        } else {

        }
    }
    //return toevoegen  overal behalve maandag
    return [aerobicMonday, crossboxMonday];
}

function sortTuesday(tuesday) {


    var aerobicTuesday = [];

    var crossboxTuesday = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < tuesday.length; i++) {
        if (aerobic.includes(tuesday[i].Activiteit)) {
            aerobicTuesday.push(tuesday[i]);
        }
        if (crossbox.includes(tuesday[i].Activiteit)) {
            crossboxTuesday.push(tuesday[i]);
        } else {

        }
    }

    return [aerobicTuesday, crossboxTuesday];

}

function sortWednesday(wednesday) {


    var aerobicWednesday = [];

    var crossboxWednesday = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < wednesday.length; i++) {
        if (aerobic.includes(wednesday[i].Activiteit)) {
            aerobicWednesday.push(wednesday[i]);
        }
        if (crossbox.includes(wednesday[i].Activiteit)) {
            crossboxWednesday.push(wednesday[i]);
        } else {

        }
    }

    return [aerobicWednesday, crossboxWednesday];

}

function sortThursday(thursday) {


    var aerobicThursday = [];

    var crossboxThursday = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < thursday.length; i++) {
        if (aerobic.includes(thursday[i].Activiteit)) {
            aerobicThursday.push(thursday[i]);
        }
        if (crossbox.includes(thursday[i].Activiteit)) {
            crossboxThursday.push(thursday[i]);
        } else {

        }
    }

    return [aerobicThursday, crossboxThursday];

}


function sortFriday(friday) {


    var aerobicFriday = [];

    var crossboxFriday = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < friday.length; i++) {
        if (aerobic.includes(friday[i].Activiteit)) {
            aerobicFriday.push(friday[i]);
        }
        if (crossbox.includes(friday[i].Activiteit)) {
            crossboxFriday.push(friday[i]);
        } else {

        }
    }

    return [aerobicFriday, crossboxFriday];

}


function sortSaturday(saturday) {


    var aerobicSaturday = [];

    var crossboxSaturday = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < saturday.length; i++) {
        if (aerobic.includes(saturday[i].Activiteit)) {
            aerobicSaturday.push(saturday[i]);
        }
        if (crossbox.includes(saturday[i].Activiteit)) {
            crossboxSaturday.push(saturday[i]);
        } else {

        }
    }

    return [aerobicSaturday, crossboxSaturday];

}

function sortSunday(sunday) {


    var aerobicSunday = [];

    var crossboxSunday = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < sunday.length; i++) {
        if (aerobic.includes(sunday[i].Activiteit)) {
            aerobicSunday.push(sunday[i]);
        }
        if (crossbox.includes(sunday[i].Activiteit)) {
            crossboxSunday.push(sunday[i]);
        } else {

        }
    }
    return [aerobicSunday, crossboxSunday];
}

function viewMonday(mondayData) {

    var aerobic = "";
    var crossbox = "";
    if (mondayData[0].length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < mondayData.length; i++) {
            aerobic += '<p>' + '<b>' + mondayData[0][i].Starttijd + ' t/m ' + mondayData[0][i].Eindtijd + '</b> - ' + mondayData[0][i].Activiteit + '</p>'
        }
    } else {
        aerobic = "geen lessen";
    }


    if (mondayData[1].length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < mondayData.length; i++) {
            crossbox += '<p>' + '<b>' + mondayData[1][i].Starttijd + ' t/m ' + mondayData[1][i].Eindtijd + '</b> - ' + mondayData[1][i].Activiteit + '</p>'
        }
    } else {
        crossbox = "geen lessen";
    }

    document.getElementById("monday-aerobic").innerHTML = aerobic;
    document.getElementById("monday-crossbox").innerHTML = crossbox;

}

function viewTuesday(tuesdayData) {



    var aerobic = "";
    var crossbox = "";
    if (tuesdayData[0].length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < tuesdayData[0].length; i++) {
            aerobic += '<p>' + '<b>' + tuesdayData[0][i].Starttijd + ' t/m ' + tuesdayData[0][i].Eindtijd + '</b> - ' + tuesdayData[0][i].Activiteit + '</p>'
        }
    } else {
        aerobic = "geen lessen";
    }



    if (tuesdayData[1].length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < tuesdayData[1].length; i++) {
            crossbox += '<p>' + '<b>' + tuesdayData[1][i].Starttijd + ' t/m ' + tuesdayData[1][i].Eindtijd + '</b> - ' + tuesdayData[1][i].Activiteit + '</p>'
        }
    } else {
        crossbox = "geen lessen";
    }


    document.getElementById("tuesday-aerobic").innerHTML = aerobic;
    document.getElementById("tuesday-crossbox").innerHTML = crossbox;

}

function viewWednesday(wednesdayData) {

    var aerobic = "";
    var crossbox = "";
    if (wednesdayData[0].length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < wednesdayData[0].length; i++) {
            aerobic += '<p>' + '<b>' + wednesdayData[0][i].Starttijd + ' t/m ' + wednesdayData[0][i].Eindtijd + '</b> - ' + wednesdayData[0][i].Activiteit + '</p>'
        }
    } else {
        aerobic = "geen lessen";
    }



    if (wednesdayData[1].length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < wednesdayData[1].length; i++) {
            crossbox += '<p>' + '<b>' + wednesdayData[1][i].Starttijd + ' t/m ' + wednesdayData[1][i].Eindtijd + '</b> - ' + wednesdayData[1][i].Activiteit + '</p>'
        }
    } else {
        crossbox = "geen lessen";
    }


    document.getElementById("wednesday-aerobic").innerHTML = aerobic;
    document.getElementById("wednesday-crossbox").innerHTML = crossbox;

}

function viewThursday(thursdayData) {

    var aerobic = "";
    var crossbox = "";
    if (thursdayData[0].length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < thursdayData[0].length; i++) {
            aerobic += '<p>' + '<b>' + thursdayData[0][i].Starttijd + ' t/m ' + thursdayData[0][i].Eindtijd + '</b> - ' + thursdayData[0][i].Activiteit + '</p>'
        }
    } else {
        aerobic = "geen lessen";
    }



    if (thursdayData[1].length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < thursdayData[1].length; i++) {
            crossbox += '<p>' + '<b>' + thursdayData[1][i].Starttijd + ' t/m ' + thursdayData[1][i].Eindtijd + '</b> - ' + thursdayData[1][i].Activiteit + '</p>'
        }
    } else {
        crossbox = "geen lessen";
    }


    document.getElementById("thursday-aerobic").innerHTML = aerobic;
    document.getElementById("thursday-crossbox").innerHTML = crossbox;

}

function viewFriday(fridayData) {
    console.log(fridayData);
    var aerobic = "";
    var crossbox = "";
    if (fridayData[0].length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < fridayData[0].length; i++) {
            aerobic += '<p>' + '<b>' + fridayData[0][i].Starttijd + ' t/m ' + fridayData[0][i].Eindtijd + '</b> - ' + fridayData[0][i].Activiteit + '</p>'
        }
    }
    else {
        aerobic = "geen lessen";
    }


    if (fridayData[1].length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < fridayData[1].length; i++) {
            crossbox += '<p>' + '<b>' + fridayData[1][i].Starttijd + ' t/m ' + fridayData[1][i].Eindtijd + '</b> - ' + fridayData[1][i].Activiteit + '</p>'
        }
    } else {
        crossbox = "geen lessen";
    }


    document.getElementById("friday-aerobic").innerHTML = aerobic;
    document.getElementById("friday-crossbox").innerHTML = crossbox;

}


function viewSaturday(saturdayData) {

    var aerobic = "";
    var crossbox = "";
    if (saturdayData[0].length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < saturdayData[0].length; i++) {
            aerobic += '<p>' + '<b>' + saturdayData[0][i].Starttijd + ' t/m ' + saturdayData[0][i].Eindtijd + '</b> - ' + saturdayData[0][i].Activiteit + '</p>'
        }
    }
    else {
        aerobic = "geen lessen";
    }


    if (saturdayData[1].length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < saturdayData[1].length; i++) {
            crossbox += '<p>' + '<b>' + saturdayData[1][i].Starttijd + ' t/m ' + saturdayData[1][i].Eindtijd + '</b> - ' + saturdayData[1][i].Activiteit + '</p>'
        }
    } else {
        crossbox = "geen lessen";
    }


    document.getElementById("saturday-aerobic").innerHTML = aerobic;
    document.getElementById("saturday-crossbox").innerHTML = crossbox;

}

function viewSunday(sundayData) {

    var aerobic = "";
    var crossbox = "";
    if (sundayData[0].length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < sundayData[0].length; i++) {
            aerobic += '<p>' + '<b>' + sundayData[0][i].Starttijd + ' t/m ' + sundayData[0][i].Eindtijd + '</b> - ' + sundayData[0][i].Activiteit + '</p>'
        }
    } else {
        aerobic = "geen lessen";
    }



    if (sundayData[1].length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < sundayData[1].length; i++) {
            crossbox += '<p>' + '<b>' + sundayData[1][i].Starttijd + ' t/m ' + sundayData[1][i].Eindtijd + '</b> - ' + sundayData[1][i].Activiteit + '</p>'
        }
    } else {
        crossbox = "geen lessen";
    }


    document.getElementById("sunday-aerobic").innerHTML = aerobic;
    document.getElementById("sunday-crossbox").innerHTML = crossbox;

}
```

```html
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.13.5/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.13.5/jszip.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="hrm.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <input type="file" id="fileUpload" />
<input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload" onclick="Upload()" />
<button  onclick="Alert()">click me</button>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <img src="https://www.hrmfitness.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Maandag_Tekengebied-1-min.png" alt="" class="img-icon-events">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-10" id="monday-aerobic">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <img src="https://www.hrmfitness.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Dinsdag_Tekengebied-1-min.png" alt="" class="img-icon-events">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-10" id="tuesday-aerobic">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <img src="https://www.hrmfitness.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Woensdag_Tekengebied-1-min.png" alt="" class="img-icon-events">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-10" id="wednesday-aerobic">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <img src="https://www.hrmfitness.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/donderdag_Tekengebied-1-min.png" alt="" class="img-icon-events">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-10" id="thursday-aerobic">
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <img src="https://www.hrmfitness.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Vrijdag_Tekengebied-1-min.png" alt="" class="img-icon-events">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-10" id="friday-aerobic">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <img src="https://www.hrmfitness.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Zaterdag_Tekengebied-1-min.png" alt="" class="img-icon-events">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-10" id="saturday-aerobic">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <img src="https://www.hrmfitness.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Zondag_Tekengebied-1-min.png" alt="" class="img-icon-events">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-10" id="sunday-aerobic">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <img src="https://www.hrmfitness.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Maandag_Tekengebied-1-min.png" alt="" class="img-icon-events">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-10"  id="monday-crossbox">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <img src="https://www.hrmfitness.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Dinsdag_Tekengebied-1-min.png" alt="" class="img-icon-events">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-10"  id="tuesday-crossbox">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <img src="https://www.hrmfitness.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Woensdag_Tekengebied-1-min.png" alt="" class="img-icon-events">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-10"  id="wednesday-crossbox">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <img src="https://www.hrmfitness.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/donderdag_Tekengebied-1-min.png" alt="" class="img-icon-events">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-10"  id="thursday-crossbox">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <img src="https://www.hrmfitness.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Vrijdag_Tekengebied-1-min.png" alt="" class="img-icon-events">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-10"  id="friday-crossbox">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <img src="https://www.hrmfitness.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Zaterdag_Tekengebied-1-min.png" alt="" class="img-icon-events">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-10"  id="saturday-crossbox">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <img src="https://www.hrmfitness.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Zondag_Tekengebied-1-min.png" alt="" class="img-icon-events">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-10"  id="sunday-crossbox">
                            </div>
                        </div>




        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

I would like the Upload function to be started but now receive the error:

```
(index): 57 Uncaught ReferenceError: Upload is not defined
     at HTMLInputElement.onclick
```

Comment: Sounds like your `Upload` is not in the global scope

Comment: I copy/pasted your code and tested it. It ran without that error. The problem must be elsewhere (most likely that you got the URL to your JS file wrong, check the Network tab to make sure it is loading properly)

Comment: I added a function sortDates it gives an error on the for loop : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier But I can't imagine what's wrong.

Comment: Have a you added all the required js file for reading excel file (mainly `XLSX` object) ?

Comment: Yes they are linked in the file before the hrm.js file

Comment: @JoppeMeijers  - I tried running it - Split Week function is not defined - Please share SplitWeek method

Comment: @user2932057 I updated the post with all html and javascript would please try again.

Comment: @JoppeMeijers - running perfectly - no change in your code

Comment: @user2932057 On a local machine it's running without error, but when I host It on a webserver it's not working. Where did you try it on?

Comment: @JoppeMeijers — Again: check the Network tab to make sure the JS file is loading properly

Comment: @Quentin yes it's loading properly

Comment: @Quentin it gives me an error on the for loop of sortDates, error: 'hrm.js:113 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier'

Comment: Then it might be a problem with data in excel. Kindly share the sample one row data

Comment: @user2932057 this error is there from the begin without uploading anything